# AVPlayer not finishing the stream track

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, audio-streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to play long audio mp3 stream music (8 minutes), short musics (1 to 3 minutes) plays perfectly, but with these bigger musics the music starts playing, but after play some random minutes (between 2 and 3:20) the player starts the track again from the beginning. Although the player restart the music, the status information (duration and current time) keeps counting normally, without restart, just the audio restarts. Someone has an idea?

The file I am playing is this: http://storage-new.newjamendo.com/download/track/57864/mp31/

The player code:

```
AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

// Assign the Playback category to the audio session.
NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
[mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                 error: &audioSessionError];

if (audioSessionError != nil) {

    NSLog (@"Error setting audio session category.");
    return;
}

// Activate the audio session
[mySession setActive: YES
               error: &audioSessionError];

if (audioSessionError != nil) {

    NSLog (@"Error activating audio session during initial setup.");
    return;
}

player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


[player play];
```

And here is how I track the information about the current time, that keeps counting normally.

```
AVPlayerItem *item = player.currentItem;

CMTime duration = [item duration];
CMTime currentTime = [item currentTime];
```

Comment: it may be related to the source of your music, I'm using AVplayer in order to play soundcloud music and I dont have problem whatsoever

Comment: @NicolasManzini I have tried with other custom players on internet (github) using the same music source and it is not happening, just with AVPlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem is that the mp3 file I was streaming was a mpeg-1 and the Apple documentation says that I have to use mpeg-2, so I have just changed to the correct version, and the error is not happening again.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I am wondering if it is the encoding (if I look at MP3 in iTunes they are using mpeg-1).  Can you tell me what software you used to encode MP3 with mpeg-2?

Comment: Yes @RecycledSteel, this made my problem less frequently, but after somedays I realised that is still happening.. So I removed the "solved" of this question.. it is still happening.. I believe that is some issue with cache, because it doesn't happen with small songs.. I found some players on github that doesn't have this problem, but unfortunately my project is too big around this player, and I would have to change too many things. I hope I can find the solution, if you do, let me know.

Comment: It would be a very large re-write for me too.  I find that the problem also happens when I stream to Safari to an iOS device (not MAC or PC).  My music is streamed in peculiar way so I am going to look into that, just tested stream same onto a Galaxy and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem, it would appear (for me) that the server was sending the file as one block.

I don't know the ins and outs but the stream is now provided as a "ranged" stream (it is provided in segments I am told).  Not only did this solve the problem but such things below started to work for me (as apposed to providing NaN).

```
float duration =  CMTimeGetSeconds(self.avQueuePlayer.currentItem.duration);
```

I hope this helps, I am not being told much about what was changed on the server.  Strangly my URL links worked on just about all other devices but I got this problem when playing from my App AND Safari.

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly you did? What changed in your code? How are you working with it?

Comment: I really need a solution, can you describe what changed in your player code?

Comment: The problem was how the stream was being provided from the server NOT in the code.  Let me plug your URL into my code and see what happens.

Comment: Yes your music restarts in my app too.  Can you give info on how the server provides the MP3?  Can you put this in your code and see what is in duration "float duration =  CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration);" - until the server was fixed I got NaN (Not a Number) here.

Comment: Yes I can get the duration normally, and it plays almost 80% of the music.. this url points to an mp3 file.. if you put the url in your browser, it will just download the music.. I have tried other players as I mentioned, and they can play this music normally, just AVPlayer is not playing it.

Comment: Any change with this?  I have been on another project but I will be back on the Audio one next week if you still want m to test.